# Debug build but with STL optimized like release build

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, release

Is it possible to compile the application code *I write* in a "debug" version (i.e. with symbols, ability to use breakpoints and step thru execution, watch variables, and all those goodies which aren't available in a release build) while forcing any underlying STL functionality to be optimized by the compiler (e.g. things like skipping array bounds checking and other performance enhancements) like a "release" build?  I don't feel the need to step down into STL code during debugging and would rather keep the code running fast and have smaller binaries.

If so, how to configure? #defines? project settings or compiler flags? And is it "safe"?

I'm using VS2019 but the question applies to g++ and other compilers as well.

I'm hoping this is a softball question for experienced programmers, but I was unable to find an answer specific to the instance when I'm compiling my code and the STL code together in one build.  (Related Q&A seems to be primarily about why not to combine executables which are compiled with one configuration with libraries compiled in the opposite configuration.)

Comment: Use the RelWithDebugInfo configuration. Although debugging in it sometimes will be confusing due to optimizations.

Comment: *"I don't feel the need to step down into STL code during debugging"* -- so don't do it? Step over those function calls instead of into them? (Your other concerns seem of low importance for a debug build, but for now I'll accept the possibility that one might find them desirable.)

Comment: I do step over them instead of into them.  What I don’t want is the ability to step into them slowing down execution of the STL code when I’m not on a breakpoint or stepping in the debugger.

Comment: In Visual Studio its not safe to mix debug and release in the same process. Structures are different sizes in Debug and there is a separate heap.

Comment: This can help quite a bit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=msvc-160 We tend to build the entire project as release with added debug info and disable optimization for the parts we're interested in debugging.